# R package alternative to plm for panel data

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I have been googling quite a lot and only found the [plm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plm/versions/2.4-0) package as a comprehensive package of tools for handling and analyzing panel data in R.

I am a novice in the field but will have to perform some analyses for my Master Thesis.

Do you have any other recommendations of R packages to handle panel data (observation size rather small with 1,000 to 50,000 observations, 20-30 vars)?

Comment: Even for smaller sample sizes you might want to try the option for faster model estimation: `options("plm.fast" = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Will check it out. Cheers, cork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many packages out there - my personal favourites that work especially well with large datasets:

- `fixest` with it's main function `feols` (apparently the fastest - see [here for an introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/vignettes/fixest_walkthrough.html))
- `lfe` with it's main function `felm` (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lfe/lfe.pdf) for an introduction)

Apart from those two, `plm` has many useful functions that you can use independent of which package you use for your actual estimation e.g. `within()`.

Answer (score 2):

The (curated) CRAN Task View *Econometrics* has a section about panel data and lists a few packages: https://cran.r-project.org/view=Econometrics

`plm` is the most versatile. However, there are more packages and most of them aim at a specific class of models.